# Parameter of constructor required a bean of type that could not be found?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following **Spring Repository**:

```
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.CosmosRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CosmosRepository<Person, String> {}
```

It is referenced here in the constructor of my **service** class:

```
private final PersonRepository personRepository ;

@Autowired
    public PersonService(
            PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository= personRepository;
    }
```

I have added this dependency in my **pom**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
  <version>3.34.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my application starter class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableSwagger2
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.example.person")
public class PersonApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

The **error** I am getting is:

```
Parameter 3 of constructor in PersonService required a bean of type 'PersonRepository' that could not be found.
    
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'PersonRepository' in your configuration.
```

What is the issue here? Am I missing another `dependency` necessary in order to use the `CosmosRepository` within my `Spring boot` application?

EDIT: when I add @EnableCosmosRepositories I get the following:

`The bean 'personRepository', defined in "com.example.PersonRepository defined in @EnableCosmosRepositories declared on CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableCosmosDbRepositoriesConfiguration, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in com.example.PersonRepository defined in @EnableCosmosRepositories declared on PersonApplication and overriding is disabled."`

Comment: Your question does not include an actual problem. Include the error you are getting, or, if no error, the behaviour you got and the different behaviour you actually wanted.

Comment: @rzwitserloot question now updated

Comment: You have defined `PersonRepository` as an `interface`.  It needs to be a `class` if you want Spring to be able to make an instance of it.

Comment: @java12399900 you need to place `@EnableCosmosRepositories` somewhere in your configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-data-cosmos-readme?view=azure-java-stable#setup-configuration-class

Comment: @java12399900 please take a look in my answer bellow to resolve your issue

Comment: @java12399900 From the `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar` class name in the latest error, it looks like along with `azure-spring-data-cosmos`, you are also using a 2.x version of `azure-spring-boot`. If so, can you switch it to a 3.x version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what is commented, the "[Azure Spring Data Cosmos client library for Java / Customizing Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-data-cosmos-readme?view=azure-java-stable#customizing-configuration)" section does mention:

> By default, `@EnableCosmosRepositories` will scan the current package for any interfaces that extend one of Spring Data's repository interfaces.
>
> Use it to annotate your Configuration class to scan a different root package by `@EnableCosmosRepositories(basePackageClass=UserRepository.class)` if your project layout has multiple projects.

Meaning:  if your repository class is not in the same package or a subpackage of your main application class, use `@EnableCosmosRepositories(basePackageClasses = PersonRepository.class)` to specify the package containing your repository class.

In your case, try:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableSwagger2
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.example.person")
@EnableCosmosRepositories(basePackageClasses = PersonRepository.class)
public class PersonApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    // ...
}
```

If your `PersonRepository` is defined in the package `com.example.person.repository`, the `@EnableCosmosRepositories(basePackageClasses = PersonRepository.class)` annotation will tell Spring Boot to scan the `com.example.person.repository` package for any interfaces extending Spring Data Cosmos DB repository interfaces.

---

The OP adds:

> When I add `@EnableCosmosRepositories`, I get the following:
>
> The bean '`personRepository`', defined in "`com.example.PersonRepository` defined in `@EnableCosmosRepositories` declared on `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableCosmosDbRepositoriesConfiguration`, could not be registered.
> A bean with that name has already been defined in `com.example.PersonRepository` defined in `@EnableCosmosRepositories` declared on `PersonApplication` and overriding is disabled.

So you have a conflict between two beans with the same name, `personRepository`: check if you have multiple `@EnableCosmosRepositories` declarations in your configuration.

If you do, try and remove the `@EnableCosmosRepositories` annotation from your `PersonApplication` class, since the `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableCosmosDbRepositoriesConfiguration` class seems to already have the annotation.
Instead, focus on updating the `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableCosmosDbRepositoriesConfiguration` class to include the package containing your PersonRepository.

But: If you do *not* have access to the `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableCosmosDbRepositoriesConfiguration` class, you can try excluding the `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` class from your Spring Boot auto-configuration, which may resolve the conflict.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
                MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class,
                CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
@EnableSwagger2
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.example.person")
@EnableCosmosRepositories(basePackageClasses = PersonRepository.class)
public class PersonApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    // ...
}
```

This should disable the auto-configuration of the `CosmosDbRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` class, leaving only your custom `@EnableCosmosRepositories` annotation in place.

---

And, As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76174075/parameter-of-constructor-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found?noredirect=1#comment134380546_76174075), make sure to use a [3.x version of `azure-spring-boot`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure.spring/azure-spring-boot) as you do for [`azure-spring-data-cosmos`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-spring-data-cosmos):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(since `azure-spring-boot` has in its "compile dependencies" `azure-spring-data-cosmos` (optional) 3.34.0)

Comment: Please see my edit, when I add this I get a different error, thanks

Comment: @java12399900 OK, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @java12399900 I see you have amended the error message (from `HierarchyRepository` to `PersonRepository`): I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have made the changes, but now I am getting this error: Parameter 0 of method setCosmosOperations in com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.repository.support.CosmosRepositoryFactoryBean required a bean of type 'com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.CosmosOperations' that could not be found.

Comment: @java12399900 Sorry for the late answer: did you resolve your error? Did you create a configuration class to define the `CosmosOperations` bean?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that in the same package `com.example` you have another class named `HierarchyRepository` which is registering another repository with the same name (`personRepository`).

Probably this is just an interface that you want to use for plain hierarchy, and in that case it should not have been registered as a spring bean.

The solution to this problem to continue to have your `HierarchyRepository` in the same scanned package is to go into this class (`HierarchyRepository`) and use the annotation `@NoRepositoryBean`. Then you would be able to use it in your code, but it will not be able to be registered as a bean, so it will not conflict with the other bean that is created from `@EnableCosmosRepositories` which is the one you need.